# calculating curl

Tags: calculus, electromagnetism, curl

> With
> $$\tilde{\mathbf{E}}=2j\hat{y}E_me^{-jk_zz}\sin(k_xx)\quad\text{for}\quad 0<x<a$$
> the phasor form of Faraday's law $\nabla\times\tilde{\mathbf{E}}=-j\omega\mu_0\tilde{\mathbf{H}}$ leads to
> $$\tilde{\mathbf{H}}=\frac{1}{-j\omega\mu_0}\begin{vmatrix}\hat{x}&\hat{y}&\hat{z}\\\frac{\partial}{\partial x}&0&\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\0&E_y&0\end{vmatrix}=\frac{-\hat{x}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}E_y+\hat{z}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}E_y}{-j\omega\mu_0}.$$

Could you please explain how to take curl of phasor $\tilde{\mathbf{E}}$? I know calculus 3, but here we have complex numbers and exponential that makes it difficult and confusing.

For example: why some are 0, some are not inside determinant?

Comment: This looks more like a curl. $\nabla\times \vec{E}\neq \nabla.\vec{E}$ .

Comment: sorry you are right it’s a curl

Comment: so do you know why

Comment: You have to review how to compute the curl, are you familiar with vector cross product ?

Comment: yes sir, I am fully aware of how to do vector cross product, if you read my post i have mentioned it there, i have taken calculus 3 at a university

Comment: I just want to clear some thing here, I’m not trying to be lazy and ask questions expecting others to do it, of course, I know how to calculate a curl, but no one has taught me how to calculate the curl of a freaking phasor with complex numbers, at least not in my university, nor I could find any online resources, so no need to answer the question, but if any advice on direction that I can follow I will follow that and try not to ask basic questions.

Comment: Please define clearly all ingredients of $\tilde{\mathbf{E}}$ in your first line. Posting just a fragment as an image makes it impossible to answer that question.

Comment: I don’t know what you’re looking for, that’s all is defined for all ingredients of E~, this is a TE wave EQUATION

Comment: What are $E_m,k_z,k_x$ ?

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment*

The vector field $\tilde{\mathbf{E}}$ has only a component in the $\hat{y}$ direction. Assuming $E_m,k_z,k_x$ are constants your $\tilde{\mathbf{E}}$ is of the form
$$\tag{1}
\tilde{\mathbf{E}}(x,z)=const.\begin{pmatrix}0\\E_y(x,z)\\0\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $E_y(x,z)=e^{-jk_zz}\sin(k_xx)\,.$ This specific form of $E_y(x,z)$ does not matter since your final equation for $\tilde{\mathbf{H}}$
does not make use of it. It also does not matter that there is the imaginary unit $j$ in $E_y(x,z)\,.$

Can you calculate the curl of (1) ?